# HTTPS redirect, no $_POST data

Tags: php, post, https

I have in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

The pages are correctly redirected to their https// "version".
However, no `$_POST` data can be read in php. That is, I always get an empty `$_POST`.
If I do not use RewriteRule, everything is fine.

I think I am missing something.

Comment: Where is your POST data being set? Ajax call? Form Submission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the url for your form into https, so it doesn't have to trigger the redirect.

Comment: Not to mention, if the request came in unencrypted, the cat is out of the bag, the data was already sent unencrypted.  It needs to be ssl from the start

Comment: But I have a lot of code using form! There is not any other solution?

Comment: Can you suggest to me how to make all the website ssl encrypted from the start? Regards

Comment: If you hardcoded all links and urls as http, you're sol.  If your urls and links are relative links, then the first GET will redirect to https, and the rest will stay https.  I Use that redirect on all my sites, but it only takes the first GET to flip it to https.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately most user-agents convert redirects on `POST` requests into `GET` requests (there is some discussion in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)). It would be preferable to not rely on this